# Copy files via powershell

Tags: powershell, copy

I have a Project that builds a bunch of dlls in the bin folder and also references others from an external lib folder. I need to be able to copy everything from the lib folder first, then from the bin folder of my app and copy all the dlls to the deployed location of my solution. 
This needs to recurse the lib folder since a lot of references are within their own folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and so i thought to share with others who might be looking to do the same. 
Here's the powershell script:

```
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Copying the LIB folder now.."
$LibFolderPath = "C:\lib"
$DestPath = "C:\website\bin\"
$BinPath = "C:\project\bin"
ForEach($file in Get-Childitem $LibFolderPath -Recur`enter code here`se -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
| Where-Object {$_.Extension -Match "dll" -or $_.Extension -Match "pdb"} )
{
Write-Host "Copying file: $file"
Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $DestPath -force 
}


Write-Host "Copying the BIN folder now.."
ForEach($file in Get-Childitem $BinPath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
| Where-Object {$_.Extension -Match "dll" -or $_.Extension -Match "pdb"} )
{
Write-Host "Copying file: $file"
Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $DestPath -force 
}
```